# Making a dynamic ListView clickable to change activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

My android app currently populates a ListView (in MainActivity) with the contents of a sqlite table. I would like to be able to click one of the created ListView Items and have it change activities to my EditNote activity, but also pass the database record relating to that ListView into EditNote, and populate the EditTexts.

My MainActivity is populates the ListView on load:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{


    DatabaseHelper dbh;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            dbh.open();

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            ArrayList<String[]> searchResult = new ArrayList<String[]>();

            //EditText searchTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchC);

            listItems.clear();

            searchResult = dbh.fetchNotes("");
            //searchResult = dbh.fetchNotes(searchTitle.getText().toString());

            String title = "", note = "";


            for (int count = 0 ; count < searchResult.size() ; count++) {

                  note = searchResult.get(count)[1];
                  title = searchResult.get(count)[0];                           

                  listItems.add(title);

            }                

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public void addNote(View v){
        Intent newActivity = new Intent (this, AddingNote.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);
        finish();
    }

}
```

My database class used to create the table and select statement:

```
public class DatabaseHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "noteDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "note";

    private OpenHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private final Context dbContext;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
                        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "title TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "note TEXT NOT NULL); ";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {

        this.dbContext = ctx;

    }

    public DatabaseHelper open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new OpenHelper(dbContext);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public boolean createNote(String title, String note) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("title", title);
        initialValues.put("note", note);

        return mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues) > 0;
    }

    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String note) {

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

        args.put("title", title);
        args.put("note", note);

        return mDb.update(TABLE_NAME, args, "_id=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    public void deleteRecord(long rowID) {
        mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_rowId=" + rowID, null);
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> fetchNotes(String title) throws SQLException {

        ArrayList<String[]> myArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        int pointer = 0;     

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id", "title",
                "note"}, null, null,
                    null, null, "_id");

        int titleColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("title");
        int noteColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("note");     

        if (mCursor != null){

           if (mCursor.moveToFirst()){

                do {
                    myArray.add(new String[3]);

                    myArray.get(pointer)[0] = mCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    myArray.get(pointer)[1] = mCursor.getString(noteColumn);
                    //increment our pointer variable.
                    pointer++;
                } while (mCursor.moveToNext()); // If possible move to the next record
           } else {

               myArray.add(new String[3]);
               myArray.get(pointer)[0] = "NO RESULTS";
               myArray.get(pointer)[1] = "";
           }
        } 

        return myArray;

    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> selectAll() {

        ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        int counter = 0;

        Cursor cursor = this.mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id", "forename", "surname", "age" }, null, null, null, null, "surname desc");

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            results.add(new String[3]);
            results.get(counter)[0] = cursor.getString(0).toString();
            results.get(counter)[1] = cursor.getString(1).toString();
            results.get(counter)[2] = cursor.getString(2).toString();
            results.get(counter)[3] = cursor.getString(3).toString();
            counter++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return results;
    }

    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

My list view XML (within activity_main.xml):

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container" >

    </ListView>
```

I'm pretty new to android development, so any help will be gratefully appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set an onClickListener to your ListView and start an Intent pointing to your EditNote activity which gets the data using:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(...);
```

---

Example:

MainActivity:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

       Intent i = new Intent(this, EditNote.class);
       i.putExtra("listItem", listItems[position]);
       startActivity(i);

}
});
```

EditNote:

String listItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("listItem");

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah that look's very much like what I'm after. However, I tried inputting that code and the "getListView()" is coming up with an error "Return type for method is missing" and suggests I change return type to void.

Comment: getListView() is a method which can only be accessed within a ListActivity (Your MainActivity is a ListActivity, right?)

Comment: Yes public class MainActivity extends ListActivity, and it is within the MainActivity class. [Screenshot of code](http://i.imgur.com/SMZ89c2.jpg)